# CSS select only content and exclude span

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
<span class="topclass">
  <a class="linkclass">
    <span class="innerclass">text</span> 1
  </a>
</span>
```

I want to style ONLY "1" and create a different style for innerclass.
Is there a way, for example using :not() selector or something else to select exactly the text inside the  tag that do not affect the `<span class="innerclass">` ?

Comment: Sorry, no that isn't possible. You could set the style on `linkclass` and set it back to the default on `innerclass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Style the a Tag (linkclass) and reset the styles for your span in the innerclass.

2) Use another span for wrapping the 1.

It really depends on the context you put this in.
Why do you put the text inside a span in the firstplace?

```
<span class="topclass">
  <a class="linkclass">
    text <span>1</span>
  </a>
</span>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that's the output code of a script, so I must use it as it is and try to style it. What I would like to obtain is that "1" can be placed at the top right corner of the text.

Comment: @user13000072 use option 1 then - style your anchor and reset your span

Comment: You can try something really tricks in that case.
https://jsfiddle.net/f0v4pc19/

But i'd rather go with Javascript enhancement.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, meanwhile you were creating the fiddle I come out at the same solution following your initial suggestion! Thanks so much!